# Flask update on refresh with data from MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, flask

I am trying to make webpage with flask which displays data from mysql table.  My code is:

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * from private')
    privateDB = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()

    return render_template('index.html', t=privateDB)
```

However whenever I refresh the page I get old data, it doesn't fetch new updated data. How to fix? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with this code

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    connection = mysql.connect()
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * from private")
    data = cursor.fetchall()

    return render_template('index.html', data=data)
```

Comment: Yep. Moving the .connect() to the function helped. Thanks

Comment: isnt this a bad practice? Having to open a new conection for each app.route?